# Javascript: editable squares

Tags: javascript, 2d, edit, polygon

How to go about drawing editable squares such as

[image]

in a javascript compatible with last version of major browsers ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://simonsarris.com/blog/510-making-html5-canvas-useful) introduction shows you how to use the HTML5 Canvas to manage shapes. And [this](http://simonsarris.com/blog/225-canvas-selecting-resizing-shape) one, shows you how to resize those shapes.

[Here's a demo of what his final product looked like](http://simonsarris.com/project/canvasdemo/demo2.html)